# how do i check to see what account is using to access the wcf services?

Tags: wcf, service, iis-6, svc

I have a WCF service hosted on IIS, and i am writing a file on the server through wcf servcie and i just wanted to make sure what credintials is using to access the services.

how do i check to see what account is using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results will depend on how you've secured your WCF service, anonymous, windows integrated, basic, are you using impersonation, etc.

In general though you can check the identity of the current process with the following:

EDIT: simple WCF method to return the account

```
public string GetUserName() {
  return System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way i can go to iis and check ?

Comment: You can check Directory Security where the WCF Service is hosted, also your web.config will say if it's using impersonation.  But using the code above you can determine the precise account being used while it's running.

Comment: `directory security` you mean to say folder where my WCF service is there? i am sure that i am not using impersonation.

Comment: Ok - I just meant that the identity will different based on how you setup your security.  To get the actual account being used you can still use the code I stated above.

Comment: ok so my `service.svc` is in dev box and i have added web reference on my project (local machine ) and will it still give me what being used on dev box or local machine? i will test your code but how would i test? confused, `note` i am consuming service from `html` pages

Comment: From the dev box you could either write the identity to the event viewer, or just create a new WCF method see GetUserName() above that returns the identity name back to your client.

Comment: i write a WCF method to just return me the `principal.Identity.Name.ToString()` and it returns me this `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` so what does it mean?

Comment: This is the account your WCF service is running as.  Network Service is a system account, likely the identity of your app pool in IIS.

Comment: so how can i assign `read/write` access to this account or should i create a new account? would you please help me? this WCF service will be on public domain

Comment: thanks for your help. here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273641/how-to-assign-application-pool-in-iis-read-write-access