# how to assign read/write access to application pool in IIS

Tags: wcf, iis-6, wcf-security, svc

so how can i assign read/write access to this account (Network Service) or should i create a new account? the WCF service will be on public domain

**i am using IIS6**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's best practice to make this a new account that you can control the direct privileges too, since Network Service can have a bit higher level of permissions.  You can change this under the Application Pool in IIS that your website hosting WCF is running as.

Then wherever your website needs the read/write access grant to this new account.

Comment: should i also assign `read/write` permission to the folder where i am storing files from `service.svc` ? here is the orginal question which triggers me to ask this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269123/writing-file-on-server-through-wcf-services

Comment: Yes - wherever your WCF code is "doing something" whether it's reading from a folder or writing to it, grant the account the appropriate permissions to do that action.

Answer (score 1):

What version of IIS are you using is usually a good thing to include in the question.

Older versions of IIS (5) use ASPNET and newer versions use [Network Service](http://www.hkvstore.com/aspnetmaker/doc/aspnet2primer.htm#permission).

You can adjust permissions as you normally do in Windows or via your Hosting Control Panel.

Comment: IIS 6 would be using NETWORK SERVICE.